# rsyslog: how to extract values from metadata and store in variable?

Tags: rhel, regular-expression, rsyslog

I currently have the following input configuration:

```
input(type="imfile"
      File="/scp_tmp/<source_ip_address>/*.log"
      addMetadata="on")
```

And two global variables:

```
set $.sourceIP = $fromhost-ip;
set $.sourceTag = $syslogtag
```

How would I be able to extract the values within `$!metadata!filename` (which should equal `/scp_tmp/127.0.0.1/audit.log` as an example) to assign `<source_ip_address>` only  to `$.sourceIP` and `audit` from the name of the log file `audit.log` to `$.sourceTag`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsyslog's scripting language [RainerScript](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/index.html) has several utility [functions](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/functions/idx_built-in_functions.html). The simplest to apply in this case is probably [field](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/functions/rs-field.html), which splits a string into fields separated by some character (given by its ascii code in decimal), or a string.  You select which of the resulting split fields you want, starting at 1. Eg:

```
field("/a/b/c", 47, 2)
```

gives the result "a" as 2nd field, since the first field is the empty space before the first "/". So you can use

```
set $.sourceIP = field($!metadata!filename, 47, 3);
```

Don't forget the ";" which is mandatory. 
You can use the same function to extract the 4th field, and then split again on the "." character to take the 1st field.

For more complicated extractions, there is [re_extract](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/functions/rs-re_extract.html) where you can use a POSIX ERE regular expression to match some part of a string, perhaps something like

```
re_extract("/a/b/c.d.log", "([^/]*).log$",0,1,"failed")
```